# Display the sum of sales volume for first half and second half and total sales volume in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on an Multi level marketing project and here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [Changu143Aa].[UserSalesVolume]
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [bigint] NULL,
    [PSV] [decimal](18, 2) NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [GSV] [decimal](18, 2) NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [DateAdded] [datetime] NULL,
    [Pin] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
)
```

I need to display the sales volume as that is sum of sales volume he got from 1-15th of the month if the current date is between 1-15th and 16-30/31st if the date belongs to 16-30/31st i write a query but its not working correctly can any body help me

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TPersonalSalesVol') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TPersonalSalesVol

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MPersonalSalesVol') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MPersonalSalesVol

CREATE TABLE #TPersonalSalesVol 
(
     TotalPSV Decimal(18, 2),
     TotalGSV Decimal(18, 2), 
     PSV Decimal(18, 2),
     GSV Decimal(18, 2), 
     MUserID bigint 
)

CREATE TABLE #MPersonalSalesVol 
(
     PSV Decimal(18, 2),
     GSV Decimal(18, 2), 
     MUserID bigINT 
)

INSERT INTO #MPersonalSalesVol (PSV, GSV, MUserID)
    SELECT
        SUM(at.PersonalSalesVolume) as PSV, 
        SUM(at.GroupSalesVolume) as GSV,at.UserID
    FROM 
        UserSalesVolume AS at 
    WHERE
        DATEPART(month,DateAdded) = DATEPART(month,GetDate())
        AND DATEPART(day,DateAdded)/16 = DATEPART(day,GetDate())/16
    GROUP BY 
        at.UserID, CONVERT(DATE, at.DateAdded, 101)

INSERT INTO #TPersonalSalesVol (TotalPSV, TotalGSV, PSV, GSV, MUserID)
    SELECT
        SUM(at.PersonalSalesVolume) as TotalPSV, 
        SUM(at.GroupSalesVolume) as TotalGSV,
        t.PSV, t.GSV, at.UserID 
    FROM
        #MPersonalSalesVol AS t 
    JOIN
        UserSalesVolume AS at ON at.UserID = t.MUserID
    GROUP BY
        at.UserID, t.PSV, t.GSV

SELECT * 
FROM #TPersonalSalesVol
```

Comment: Does a stored procedures works for you?

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE @CurDate datetime2(7) = '2016-10-16'
DECLARE @Year int = YEAR(@CurDate)
DECLARE @Month int = MONTH(@CurDate)
-- Calc Day Range
DECLARE @StartDay int = CASE WHEN DAY(@CurDate) <= 15 THEN 1 ELSE 16 END
DECLARE @EndDay int = CASE WHEN DAY(@CurDate) <= 15 THEN 15 ELSE 31 END

SELECT UserID, SUM(PSV), SUM(GSV)

FROM UserSalesVolume

WHERE  YEAR(DateAdded) = @Year AND MONTH(DateAdded) = @Month 
    AND DAY(DateAdded) BETWEEN @StartDay AND @EndDay

GROUP BY UserID